# Broken git repo after git lfs migrate

Tags: git, git-lfs

Improper use of git lfs migrate --everything somehow generated a .gitattributes file with every known file type.  This has basically nuked our project, as all files of every type now look something like this:

```
    version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
    oid sha256:f6d1237f5b00a49b32cca659d9764fc16cf012ea887c3007bf9a2120d7e9fef4
    size 792
```

..throughout the entire repo history.  The containing directory is still roughly the same filesize which gives me hope that there is a way of recovering this, but I haven't been able to work it out myself.

Due to unusual circumstances this repo was not yet on github - there's a copy of the repo that we can restore to if needed but would mean losing a couple of days work.

Is there any way to undo the lfs command?

This is how the .gitattributes file ended up being generated somehow:

```
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.rar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mp4 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.collabignore filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gitignore filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.xml filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.iml filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.meta filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mat filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.prefab filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.shader filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.FBX filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.txt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.cs filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pdf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dae filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mixer filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.compute filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.asset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.cginc filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.unity filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.controller filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mask filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.blend filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.blend1 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.anim filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.exr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.renderTexture filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.json filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ttf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.TTF filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.otf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.asd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.PSD filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.sfk filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.PNG filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.terrainlayer filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.zip filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.inputactions filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lighting filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Still not entirely sure how this came to happen, but have fixed it simply by running
`git lfs checkout`

Leaving this here as other people as googling around just came up with a load of unresolved threads

Comment: You save my project !

Comment: Thank you for this, exactly the command to run to fix this for me. Apparently no project of mine is complete without a git emergency happening at least once...

Step By Step on what happened in my case:
1) Getting git errors trying to upload a ".asset" file over 100mb to git 
2) Decide that way to fix this is to use `git lfs migrate import --include="*.asset"`
3) All .asset files now changed to the format of your first code block
4) Freak out
5) use `git lfs checkout` 
6) Pop Champagne, issues fixed.

Thanks so much.

Comment: WOW!!! I was hopeless then you saved my life « Leaving this here » people are the best people ever...

Comment: This is one of the most live-saving answers I've ever seen.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you end up changing `.gitattributes`, or did you leave the lines there?