# Why are all my Unreal Engine uasset files missing after using git lfs migrate import --include="*.uasset"

Tags: git, unreal-engine4, git-lfs

I was trying to add large file support for my Unreal Engine project. After adding LFS support I then found the following command to make sure that all the large files where added throughout my version history.

git lfs migrate import --include="*.uasset"

After running this command I know notice that NON of my blueprints or assets inside the content browser are showing up. If I browse to the file system all the .uasset files are there.

I'm not sure how to get the .uassets to show up in Unreal Editor again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It seems after the command:

```
    git lfs migrate import
```

You need to run:

```
    git lfs checkout
```

Original answer:
[Broken git repo after git lfs migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060941/broken-git-repo-after-git-lfs-migrate)